# Lambda timeouts with calls to external api when scaling up

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency, timeout

I have set up a lambda A (Nodejs) which gathers data from other lambdas B,C,D,... by invoking them synchronously. These other lambdas call an external API. The issue is that when there is traffic, these other lambdas (B,C,D,  ...) timeout their request to this external API. With a single invokation of Lambda A, these other lambdas perform their external api http request in under a second, but under load, the time keeps increasing.

The timeout is set at 10 seconds so reattempting can be made, but I tried changing this to a minute just to see if I get a response, and it does happen. It seems as if there is not enough of *something* available and subsequent requests get queued.

There are no errors in logs (regarding hitting AWS limits) and I'm not hitting AWS Concurrency limits. I also thought I could be hitting burst concurrency limits, but there are no errors in logs.

[image]

(Graph shows sum per minute)

How can the ConcurrentExecutions be so high if there are only 366 invocations?

I have started fiddling around with maxSockets (I wasn't aware that Infinity equals to only 50), but I'm thinking it is not set correctly at the moment. Could this however be the case, eq. it only can process 50 connections at a time and rest are queued?

Code below (mock).

```js
const soapConfig = {
  endpoint: 'https://soapapi.com',
  options: { timeout: 29000, time: true, pool: { maxSockets: Infinity },
    wsdl: `${__dirname}/ASC2021.wsdl`
  }
}

const handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  let processed = (async function () {
    let params = Object.assign({}, event.pathParameters, event.queryStringParameters)
    const client = await soap.createClientAsync(soapConfig.wsdl,
      soapConfig.options, soapConfig.endpoint)
    const result = await client.GetData(params, soapConfig.options)
    return result
  })()
  postProcess(processed, context, callback)
}
```

`AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED` is set to 1

Could there *some* queue *somewhere* that I'm hitting?

EDIT: I forgot to add that I have had detailed discussions with the API maintainer and the calls do not even reach said api. If timeout is raised to said 1 minute, the api receives the request but near the end of the request. There are also no limits on the API.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned under "Using Performance Metrics" at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html you should be using "Maximum" metric not "Sum" for "ConcurrentExecutions".
Using "Sum" will not make sense.

By what you explained your use-case there seems to API limit that you can call per second to external API (maybe 50 requests per second as per your information).
When you are exceeding the limit your lambda retries resulting into longer execution times, eventually timing out under load.
You can leverage ReservedConcurrency feature of lambda to limit your lambda to exceed external api limit.
And, apply some backoff logic on throttling errors codes to be graceful to your downstream services.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I forgot to mention though that I have discussed with the API maintainers and the issue is not on their end. The calls do not even reach their API unless timeout is raised. So it is definitely on my end.

Comment: Are your lambda using any downstream service that could be bottlenecking the requests ? It is not possible that there is no limit. Must be not known by the API maintainer. Even AWS which claims scaling infinitely effortlessly has limits.

Comment: No. There are no downstream services. And if there is a limit on the API end, it is not within my scope. The issues arise with even just 20 concurrent requests.

Comment: I deployed multiple projects with ConcurrentExecutions of 100s to 3000 at a time. They only had similar issue when the downstream API limit turned out to be bottleneck. And, all I had to is leverage ReservedConcurrency to keep in check.

Comment: Thanks for the input. We looked at the logs of the external api and when the requests finally reached the API they were processed in seconds max. Of course, there could be something else limiting the requests on their end, but I have to live with their input for now and belive it is not on their end.

However, now when I think about it, limiting concurrency could be a good workaround. This would allow AWS SDK to do the reattempting if there is too many concurrent instances running. Thanks.